# Extract data from MATLAB matrix without for-loop

Tags: matlab, matrix, vectorization

In MATLAB, let us say I have a 10 x 100 matrix, called `M`. What I would like to do, is extract particular indicies of this matrix, and do an operation on them immediately, *based on the row index*, in a vectorized fashion.

For example, for the first row, I want to compute `sum(M(1, 1:1:100))`. Then for row two, I want `sum(M(2, 1:2:100))`. For row three, I want `sum(M(3, 1:3:100))`, etc etc. For row ten, I have of course `sum(M(10, 1:10:100))`.

I have this in a for loop, but I want to see if there is a way to extract this data without a for loop. Thank you.

Comment: Why do you want to avoid a loop? Are you experiencing performance issues?

Comment: @EitanT Yes,  guess its not THAT big of a deal, but there might be potential performance issues down the line, so I am trying to see if there is a more elegant way.

Comment: Pro tip: don't optimize code before benchmarking. Leave it as is, unless you're certain that _this_ is the bottleneck.

Comment: As [D. Knuth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Donald_Knuth) said: "*[...: premature optimization is the root of all evil.](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization)*"

Comment: @OlegKomarov Ha! Thanks for the link ... I will just say that I am curious of how this can be done either way, for my own learning. I am a learnaholic after all... ;-)

Comment: Your question is not trivial and I am afraid that anything but a loop would be of higher complexity. However, it could be a challenge for the vectorize-at-all-costs maniacs :D.

Comment: @OlegKomarov I agree. I think perhaps a matrix multiplication with a pre-made binary matrix might be a way...

Comment: What are you doing with the result of the computation?

Comment: Added a truly vectorized solution [**here**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26949235/3293881), assuming you are still interested in finding a vectorized solution to it or just for learning maybe going by your handle here :)

Comment: Thanks @Divakar Ill have to sit down and study it! :)

Comment: @Learnaholic Well I had to sit down and brain-storm about this one until the stated approach struck me, so take your time!

Comment: @Divakar Yes it looks like you put a lot of time into it. It's saturday now - go out and have some fun to reward yourself! :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this for a one-liner

```
S=arrayfun(@(n) sum(M(n,1:n:100)), 1:10)
```

Alternatively, you can create a sparse matrix beforehand

```
A=sparse(100,10);
for n=1:10, 
   A(1:n:100, n)=1; 
end
```

and find the sum by

```
S=diag(M*A);
```

This can be optimized further for larger matrices by defining `A=sparse(10,100)` and

```
S=sum(M.*A,2);
```

my quick benchamrking

```
M=rand(10,100);
sz = size(M);
tic;
for k=1:10000,
    for n=1:sz(1),
        B(n)=sum(M(n,1:n:end));
    end
end
toc

tic;
for k=1:10000,
    B=arrayfun(@(n) sum(M(n,1:n:end)), 1:sz(1));
end
toc

tic;
for k=1:10000,
    A=sparse(sz(2), sz(1));
    for n=1:sz(1),
        A(1:n:end, n)=1;
    end
    B=diag(M*A);
end
toc

tic;
A=sparse(sz(2),sz(1));
for n=1:sz(1),
    A(1:n:end, n)=1;
end
for k=1:10000,
    B=diag(M*A);
end
toc

tic;
A=sparse(sz(1),sz(2));
for n=1:sz(1),
    A(n, 1:n:end)=1;
end
for k=1:10000,
    B=sum(M.*A,2);
end
toc
```

returns

```
Elapsed time is 0.552470 seconds.
Elapsed time is 2.409102 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.638072 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.052246 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.061893 seconds.
```

for 30-by-1000 matrix

```
Elapsed time is 1.785664 seconds.
Elapsed time is 3.954034 seconds.
Elapsed time is 4.760436 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.926118 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.865330 seconds.
```

and for 1000-by-100 matrix

```
Elapsed time is 51.389322 seconds.
Elapsed time is 63.443414 seconds.
Elapsed time is 68.327187 seconds.
Elapsed time is 29.056304 seconds.
Elapsed time is 1.147215 seconds.
```

Comment: Arrayfun is a concealed loop and will suffer from overhead in comparison to a plain loop. This solution is not purely vectorized.

Comment: The question asked is "if there is a way to extract this data without a for loop". And this qualifies as an answer to that question.

Comment: I do consider `arrayfun()`, `cellfun()`, `structufun()` and all functions that have MATLAB code that execute a loop to be non-vectorized solutions. This is not just my personal opinion, but is widely assumed to be so especially because vectorized often stands for performance. In this perspective, only `cellfun('stringInput',c)` might be faster than an explicit loop.

Comment: Mohsen I like your solutions... can you please benchmark the straight up for loop against the last sparse solution you provided? I think that might be the one... thanks so much.

Comment: Fantastic! Looks like an entire order of magnitude gain with last sparse solution... brilliant! :)

Comment: added the benchmark for for-loop and the performance is close to sparse matrix case, unless you need to do this on multiple matrices then you can reuse A matrix and gain on performance.

Comment: Your plain loop indices with `k` and sums `A` instead of `M`. Would also be nice if you posted the whole testing suite with the creation of inputs.

Comment: You are forgetting to preallocate the plain loop which boosts it to second best but far behind the sparse/elementwisemult. To be fully coherent, you need to convert the sparse back to full, which however has minor impact.

Comment: preallocating has a tiny effect here. The B matrix will be allocated in the first time the innermost for loop is run and will be preallocated for the rest of 9999 times the for loop runs.

Answer (score 5):

### Proposed solution

I was able to finally crack it for a truly vectorized solution that uses `logical indexing` to select the elements from the input matrix that are to be summed up. This magic was achieved with `bsxfun` with its optional functional handle `@mod`. The code is listed below -

```
[m,n] = size(M);
mask = bsxfun(@mod,1:n,(1:m)')==1; %//'# all of magic happens here as it creates 
                             %// a logical mask of 1's at places in input matrix
                             %// whose elements are to be summed and 0's elsewhere.
mask(1,:) = 1; %// set the first row as all ones as we need to sum all of those
sumvals = sum(mask.*M,2); %// finally get the sum values
```

### Benchmarking

In this benchmarking section I am including the four approaches - The one listed earlier in this post and its GPU ported version, 
`arrayfun` and `sparse` based approaches listed in [the other solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17070521/3293881).

Three sets of input data were used for the benchmarking -

- `Set 1`: Number of columns is kept at a multiple factor of `10` with respect to the number of rows in the input matrix as used in the question.
- `Set 2`: The number of rows are extended so that number of rows is now `10x` number of columns. This would really test out the loopy codes, as the
  number of iterations would be more in this case.
- `Set 3`: This set is an extension of `set2`, to further increase the number of rows and thus would be another great test between truly vectorized approaches
  against others.

The function codes used for benchmarking are listed next -

```
function sumvals = sumrows_stepped_bsxfun(M)
//... same as the code posted earlier
return

function sumvals = sumrows_stepped_bsxfun_gpu(M)
gM = gpuArray(M);
[m,n] = size(gM);
mask = bsxfun(@mod,gpuArray.colon(1,n),gpuArray.colon(1,m)')==1; %//'
sumvals = gather(sum(mask.*gM,2));
sumvals(1) = sum(M(1,:));
return

function S = sumrows_stepped_arrayfun(M)
[m,n] = size(M);
S = arrayfun(@(x) sum(M(x,1:x:n)), 1:m);
return

function B = sumrows_stepped_sparse(M)
sz = size(M);
A=sparse(sz(1),sz(2));
for n=1:sz(1),
    A(n, 1:n:end)=1;
end
B=full(sum(M.*A,2));
return
```

Please note that `timeit` was used for timing `CPU based` codes and `gputimeit` for `GPU based` codes.

System Configuration used for testing -

```
MATLAB Version: 8.3.0.532 (R2014a)
Operating System: Windows 7
RAM: 3GB
CPU Model: Intel® Pentium® Processor E5400 (2M Cache, 2.70 GHz)
GPU Model: GTX 750Ti 2GB
```

The benchmarking results thus obtained -

[image]

[image]

[image]

### Conclusions

1. For datasizes with number of rows lesser than the number of columns, the number of iterations being a small number, loopy codes seem to have the upper-hand.
2. As we increase the number of rows, the benefit of truly vectorized approaches become clear. You would also notice that `bsxfun on CPU` based approach does well for set 3, until around `12000 x 300` mark against non vectorized approaches and the reason behind that is, `bsxfun` creates this huge logical mask  and at that point the memory bandwidth requirement becomes too high to cope up with the compute capability of `bsxfun`. This makes sense as vectorized operations by definition mean performing operations on many elements in one go, so memory bandwidth is essential. So, if you have a better machine with more RAM, that `12000 x 300` mark should extend further.
3. If you could extend the number of rows further, the benefits of a vectorized solution would become more clear as long as the memory bandwidth is kept in check.

### Benchmarking Code

Finally here's the benchmarking code if anyone would like to test it out on their systems -

```
clear all; clc; close all

outputfile = 'results.xlsx';
delete(outputfile); %// remove file, so that new results could be written into

base_datasize_array = 40:60:400;
methods = {'BSXFUN on GPU','BSXFUN on CPU','ARRAYFUN','SPARSE'};
num_approaches = numel(methods);
num_sets = 3;

timeall_all = zeros(num_approaches,numel(base_datasize_array),num_sets);
datasize_lbs = cell(numel(base_datasize_array),num_sets);
for set_id = 1:num_sets
    switch set_id
        case 1
            N1_arr = base_datasize_array*2;
            N2_arr = N1_arr*10;
        case 2
            N2_arr = base_datasize_array*2;
            N1_arr = N2_arr*10;
        case 3
            N2_arr = base_datasize_array;
            N1_arr = N2_arr*40;
    end

    timeall = zeros(num_approaches,numel(N1_arr));
    for iter = 1:numel(N1_arr)
        M = rand(N1_arr(iter),N2_arr(iter));

        f = @() sumrows_stepped_bsxfun_gpu(M);
        timeall(1,iter) = gputimeit(f); clear f

        f = @() sumrows_stepped_bsxfun(M);
        timeall(2,iter) = timeit(f); clear f

        f = @() sumrows_stepped_arrayfun(M);
        timeall(3,iter) = timeit(f); clear f

        f = @() sumrows_stepped_sparse(M);
        timeall(4,iter) = timeit(f); clear f

    end
    timeall_all(:,:,set_id) = timeall;

    wp = repmat({' '},numel(N1_arr),1);
    datasize_lbs(:,set_id) = strcat(cellstr(num2str(N1_arr.')),' x ',...
        wp,cellstr(num2str(N2_arr.')));
end

for set_id=1:num_sets
    out_cellarr = cell(numel(methods)+1,numel(N1_arr)+1);
    out_cellarr(1,1) = {'Methods'};
    out_cellarr(2:end,1) = methods;
    out_cellarr(1,2:end) = datasize_lbs(:,set_id);
    out_cellarr(2:end,2:end) = cellfun(@(x) num2str(x),...
        num2cell(timeall_all(:,:,set_id)),'Uni',0);
    xlswrite(outputfile, out_cellarr,set_id);
end
```

Comment: Kudos! except that the figures are made in Excel, Matlab can produce equally ugly plots :)

Comment: @Arpi Yeah! Well MATLAB plots don't look that "sleek", so made that switch! ;) Think it's less ugly with excel!

Answer (score 1):

Since there is an interesting performance effect in the sparse/matrixmult approach I will post some adidtional results:

```
M  = rand(1000,100);
sz = size(M);

% PLAIN LOOP
tic
out1 = zeros(sz(1),1);
for k = 1:10000
    for n = 1:sz(1)
        out1(n) = sum(M(n,1:n:100));
    end
end
toc

% SPARSE MATRIXMULT
tic
A = sparse(sz);
for n = 1:sz(1)
    A(1:n:sz(2),n) = 1;
end
for k = 1:10000
    out2 = diag(M*A);
end
toc

isequal(out1,out2) % ok  

Plain loop:        11.441380 seconds.
Sparse/matrixmult: 27.503829 seconds.
```

As the dimension of the matrix grows, the **plain loop** is more efficient.

Comment: Some additional details pertinent to my problem: 1) The number of rows of M are going to be ~30 max, and the columns will be ~1000 or more. 2) Also, you may assume that the sparse matrix can be done once, no need to always remake it. What would perform better in the bench marks with those details? Thanks.

Comment: With `M` 30x1000 I get plain loop 0.439726 seconds and sprase/matrixmult 0.858779 seconds where the creation of `A` takes only 0.004381 seconds (I had in mind a way to speed that up, but it's pointless).

Comment: Ok, interesting... I guess for my case a for loop would be faster... hmmm.. where/when would the advantage of the sparse matrix appear then?

Comment: there is a more efficient way. I added that as fifth method and put the benchmark. It performs really well for the extreme case Oleg mentioned.